# Xamarin android crashing off debugging

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, usb-debugging

I am creating a Xamarin android application it worked fine for a long time but now it is crashing when I run it without a debugger attached (installed on device) and working fine while debugging with visual studio (connected to the laptop). What seems to be the problem.

here is my androidmanifest.xml file for a look

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="{PACKAGE NAME}" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
  <!-- Google Maps for Android v2 requires OpenGL ES v2 -->
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
  <!-- Permission to receive remote notifications from Google Play Services -->
  <!-- Notice here that we have the package name of our application as a prefix on the permissions. -->
  <uses-permission android:name="{PACKAGE NAME}.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
  <permission android:name="{PACKAGE NAME}.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <!-- These are optional, but recommended. They will allow Maps to use the My Location provider. -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


  <application android:name="android.app.Application" android:allowBackup="true" android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" android:debuggable="true" android:extractNativeLibs="true" android:icon="@drawable/appiconfinal" android:label="Problem Update" android:roundIcon="@drawable/appiconfinal" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <!-- Necessary for apps that target Android 9.0 or higher -->
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />


    <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="{PACKAGE NAME}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </provider>
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.CreateIssue" android:label="CreateIssue" />
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.createissue2" android:label="createissue2" />
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.createissue3" android:label="createissue3" />
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.createissue4" android:label="createissue4" />
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.createissue5" android:label="createissue5" />
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.createissue6" android:label="createissue6" />
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.EmailVerifyActivity" android:label="EmailVerifyActivity" />
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.ForgotPassActivity" android:label="ForgotPassActivity" />
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.FundsActivity" android:label="FundsActivity" />
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.LocationActivity" android:label="LocationActivity" />act
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.LocationsActivity" android:label="LocationsActivity" />
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.Login" android:label="Login" >

    </activity>
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.testActivity" android:label="testActivity">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.MapActivity" android:label="MapActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.Newpassword" android:label="Newpassword" />
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.NotificationsActivity" android:label="NotificationsActivity" />
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.OTPVerify" android:label="OTPVerify" />
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.PhotoUploading" android:label="PhotoUploading" />
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.Register1Activity" android:label="Register1Activity" />
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.Register2Activity" android:label="Register2Activity" />
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.Register3Activity" android:label="Register3Activity" />
    <activity android:name="crc64830617e3579ebeb9.SettingsActivity" android:label="SettingsActivity" />
    <activity android:name="crc644f28929abffd59e1.HomeActivity" android:label="HomeActivity" />
    <activity android:name="crc646957603ea1820544.MediaPickerActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|uiMode" />
    <service android:name="crc64396a3fe5f8138e3f.KeepAliveService" />
    <receiver android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.BatteryBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Battery Broadcast Receiver" />
    <receiver android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.EnergySaverBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Energy Saver Broadcast Receiver" />
    <receiver android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Connectivity Broadcast Receiver" />
    <provider android:name="xamarin.essentials.fileProvider" android:authorities="{PACKAGE NAME}.fileProvider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/xamarin_essentials_fileprovider_file_paths" />
    </provider>
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:authorities="{PACKAGE NAME}.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="1999999999" />
    <!-- suppress ExportedReceiver -->
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
        <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.{PACKAGE NAME}" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:exported="false" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <!-- suppress ExportedReceiver -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="{API KEY}"/>

    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
        <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <!--FCM RECEIVER ENDS HERE-->


  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: According to the code you provided, we could not find what cause this issue. Could you provide more details? Have you test with the sane version of the device and emulator? When you use the debugger with device, do you get the same error?

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is solved, I explored the Cat Log while launching application and found that the error was due to the null value provided to the newtonsoft.json deserializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with the AndroidManifest.xml file or application build settings, it was due to the null value object at main activity.
PS: Discovered it by viewing Cat Log while launching the application on mobile without debugging.